# Socket programming simple example in c sharp

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, asyncsocket, socketexception

I create a simple application in socket programming. I think this is simple way to achieved that. so that is why I am sharing this.
In this program you can create server program and client program. And you can also send and received message from client and server.
here is my code

**Server Program :-**

```
class Program
    {
        private const int port = 4532;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                      

            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4532);
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            socket.Bind(ip);
            socket.Listen(10);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client");
            Socket client = socket.Accept();
            IPEndPoint clientIP = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Connected with" + clientIP.Address + "at port" + clientIP.Port);
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Accept connection from client");

            string welcome = "Welcome";
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
            client.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            Console.WriteLine("......");
            Console.Read();

        }

    }
```

**Client Program :-**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4532);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Started");
            try
            {
                socket.Connect(ip);
            }
            catch(SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enable to connect");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Conneted to server");

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int receivedata = socket.Receive(data);
            string stringdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedata);
            Console.WriteLine(stringdata);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not entirely right.

Note that `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` will give you a new array each time, so that `new byte[1024]` initialization is worthless, the array maybe bigger if the string is bigger.

What happen if the server sends a payload more than 1024? The client will truncate the message, that will cause serialization errors if you are using a structured data format like XML or JSON. In TCP communications you need to define a protocol to frame data, in a way that your code can determine when a message has started or ended, for example a message per line or something more sophisticated like the WebSocket framing.

Note that the server will accept just one client, send a welcome and get stuck in `Console.Read`. It should listen for more clients in a loop, and start a new thread per connected client or use asynchronous operations. Same for the client ,it should listen for messages in a loop.

Consider async/await for expanding your example further. A production ready TCP server needs to be multithreading to scale appropriately.

Take a look at this example of [asynchronous TCP server and client](https://github.com/vtortola/AynchronousTCPListener), not production ready, but enough for a proof of concept with buffer reading and asynchronous operations.